# Are double[] GenerateArray() and void GenerateArray(ref double[]) the Same

Tags: c#

Whenever c++ returns an object, all of the contents of the objects are copied to the new object once the method is returned, but in C# there is no such thing, AFAIK.

My question is, in C#, are the below two equivalent in terms of speed and memory consumption?

```
double[] GenerateArray()
```

and

```
void GenerateArray(ref double[] result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be pretty-much on a par; note that `out` would be preferred over `ref` here. However, since there is no clear distinction in performance, I would strongly suggest the more idiomatic `double[] GenerateArray()` via `return` is a much better implementation; not least, `out`/`ref` is a constant source of confusion, and may often require introducing an extra variable for the purpose (rather than using the return value as an expression).

Very minor, but this also means there is one less indirection *inside* `GenerateArray` - meaning: with the `ref`/`out` usage, any access on `result` needs to first dereference the `ref` to get the array reference, *then* dereference to the array.

Comment: One other difference is that `out` parameters are not covariant.

Comment: @CodeInChaos true, but `double` arrays aren't covarient either ;p